# Collapse multiple rows of arrays if the arrays overlap

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL 9.3 that contains a single column
containing an array in each row. I am trying to find a way to collapse
rows of arrays that share the same elements.

### Examples

**simple overlap**

Given the following two rows with arrays:

```
{ 1, 2, 3 }
{ -5, 3, 6, 9 }
```

The result would be a row containing:

```
{ -5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9 }
```

This is because the "3" exists in both arrays. Note that the "3" is not repeated.

**multiple overlaps**

The same overlap concept can also apply to multiple rows anywhere in the table:

```
{ 1, 2, 3 }
{ 100, 200, 300 }
{ 3, 4, 5 }
{ 5, 6, 7 }
```

and the desired output would be two rows :

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
{ 100, 200, 300 }
```

The arrays returned from the result should be unique and share no elements with each other.

### What I've tried

I used a "with recursive" query with [array union](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/intarray.html) function, but couldn't figure out the right query.

A sample table to work with is provided [here on SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b05d8/3/0) (it mimics the second example), or it can be built with:

```sql
create table test ( 
  arr integer[] 
); 

insert into test (arr) values ('{ 1, 2, 3 }');
insert into test (arr) values ('{ 100, 200, 300 }');
insert into test (arr) values ('{ 3, 4, 5 }');
insert into test (arr) values ('{ 5, 6, 7 }');
```

Comment: For this sort of question, it's really nice if you provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with usable sample tables.

Comment: @CraigRinger that's a neat site. I couldn't figure it out but here is a usable table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b05d8/3/0 . Went ahead and added it into the question.

Comment: @TrevorSenior Hmm, interesting query. You can't self join in `with recursive` or use a subquery over the recursive term, and I don't think you can do this with aggregates unless you had a way to `group by` overlapping terms, which I'm not convinced is possible. You may have to use a recursive SQL function. A single pass is `SELECT 
    uniq(array_cat(a.arr, b.arr))
FROM test a
INNER JOIN test b ON (b.arr > a.arr AND a.arr && b.arr)` but that doesn't help much.

Comment: If the table is small enough, you may be able to get away with doing it in a programming language like python?

Answer (score 3):

OK, it was tough. Please have a look at this query:

```
;with recursive minelem AS(
select arr, MIN(unnest) minel from (select arr, unnest(arr) from test) a group by arr),
testwithrn as(
select arr, row_number() over (order by minel) rn from minelem
),
cte(arr, rn, counter, grp) as(
  select arr, rn, 1, 1 from testwithrn where rn = 1
union all 
  select 
    case when array_length(a.arr & b.arr, 1) > 0 then a.arr | b.arr else b.arr end, 
    b.rn, 
    case when array_length(a.arr & b.arr, 1) > 0 then a.counter + 1 else 1 end,
    case when array_length(a.arr & b.arr, 1) > 0 then a.grp else a.grp + 1 end
    from cte a inner join testwithrn b 
    on b.rn > a.rn
),
grouped as(
  SELECT arr, counter, grp,
  row_number() over (partition by grp order by counter desc) rn from cte)
select distinct arr from grouped where rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3c19/1)

You can test different CTEs in the query above to understand how I have come up with the solution. The key here is to use operator | to merge arrays, as in `a.arr | b.arr`

There is a recursive query called `cte` that counts the occurrence of each set within different groups of sets. You can replace the last line to `select * from cte order by grp, counter` to see how the `counter` and `grp` are changed when the sets are recursively built