# Unions of intersecting sets

Tags: postgresql, union-find

I have a table representing sets of records like

```
set_id | record_id
     a |         1
     a |         2
     a |         3
     b |         2
     b |         4
     b |         5
     c |         6
     c |         7
     d |         9
     d |        11
     e |        10
     f |        11
     f |        12
```

I want to yield output like this

```
output
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
{6, 7}
{9, 11, 12}
{10}
```

Where intersecting sets are combined (notice set **a** and set **b** have been combined; **d** and **f** have also been combined).

Is there a good way of doing this with SQL, not a stored procedure. I know that I'm looking for a kind of Union-Find procedure.

Comment: can obtain more than one intersection? a + b + d?

Comment: @McNets, yes, that's needed.

Comment: if you would have rows (d, 9), (e,10) and (d,11) - would you look for {9,11} and {10} or for {9,10,11} ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, I edited the question to elaborated those cases

Comment: does my solution work for you?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, this does not work if there's more than one intersecting set

Comment: @fgregg fixed for new set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapse multiple rows of arrays if the arrays overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715809/collapse-multiple-rows-of-arrays-if-the-arrays-overlap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prepare:

```
so=> create table so75(set_id text, record_id int);
CREATE TABLE
so=> copy so75 from stdin;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> ^CERROR:  COPY from stdin failed: canceled by user
CONTEXT:  COPY so75, line 1
so=> copy so75 from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>>      a |         1
 a |         2
 a |         3
 b |         2
 b |         4
 b |         5
 c |         6
 c |         7
 d |         9
 d |        11
 e |        10
 f |        11
 f |        12   
>> >> >> >> >> >> >>
>> \.
COPY 14
```

qry:

```
so=> with keys as (
  with a as (
    select *,count(1) over (partition by record_id) c, array_agg(set_id) over(partition by record_id) cc
    from so75
  )
  select set_id, cc
  from a where c > 1
)
select distinct array_agg(distinct record_id)
from so75
left outer join keys on keys.set_id = so75.set_id
group by case when array_length(cc,1) > 1 then cc::text else so75.set_id end;
  array_agg
-------------
 {6,7}
 {10}
 {1,2,3,4,5}
 {9,11,12}
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I noticed duplicates (lacked distinct) and bug with extra set_id (lacked case in group by) and fixed it - check if new code does not work either?.. cos it does on my machine

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2a52cc6209eac586f2cb4a1472b3ccf9 sorry I'm not good with fiddle. ```{6,7}
{1,3}
{2,4,5}``` is it wrong?..

Comment: http://rextester.com/WCDX49467 sorry - I must miss something: `('a',2),('a',4),('b',2),('b',4),('b',5),('c',6),('c',7),('d',1),('d',3)` , so `a,b`: {2,4,5} and `c`:6,7 and `d`:1,3 - right?..

Comment: ah! I see noe - I totally misunderstood the task! Intersects - you mean 2 is included in array from 1 to 3! I thought intersects - values in common! So I sovled the different task :)

Comment: Yes, This is it.

Comment: Yes, nice an simple.

Comment: On this data, I get duplicate output:
```insert into so75 values
('a',2),('a',4),('b',2),('b',4),('b',5),('c',6),('c',7),('d',1),('d',3);```

Comment: because of possible pairs {ab} and {ba} - added `distinct` to fix